# How can I embed an HTML5 canvas in Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms, html5

I am trying to create a drawing response in Google Forms. I am looking to create an add-on using Google Script to make this happen. I am thinking that I will have to use HTML5 canvas, but I'm not quite sure how.

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script could be used to create forms, to add custom features to the Google Forms editor, to submit responses automatically and to do things on form submission but it **could not** add features to published forms like the embedding an HTML5 canvas.